# Optimization for INNER JOIN with optional fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a query like this...

```
SELECT master.FIELD_X, rules.FIELD_Y 
    FROM T_MASTER master
    INNER JOIN T_RULES rules ON 
        master.KEY = rules.KEY AND
        (master.FIELD1 = rules.FIELD1 OR rules.FIELD1 IS NULL) AND
        (master.FIELD2 = rules.FIELD2 OR rules.FIELD2 IS NULL) AND
        ...
        (master.FIELDN = rules.FIELDN OR rules.FIELDN IS NULL)
    WHERE master.KEY = <value>
```

Basically,

- T_MASTER contains around 500.000 rows per KEY value.
- T_RULES table (around 2000 rows) contains rules to select records from T_MASTER.
- Each of those rules can be specified by several optional fields (Can contain a value or been null).

Currently, with the volume above (T_MASTER ~500k / T_RULES ~2k rows), this query is taking around 10 minutes to run which even could be acceptable (this is running in a batch), I understand can be further improved or indicate some bad design on the query / DB structure.

Any idea?

Some examples of rules:

```
Rule_1:  If Field2 = 'foo' and Field7 = 'bar' => Field_Y = 'rule_1_value'
Rule_2:  If Field3 = 'value' => Field_Y = 'rule_2_value'
```

Comment: Do you have any index setup on the field columns?  This is one possible way you could make the query run faster.  Have a look at the query execution plan to perhaps see what the bottlenecks are in the query.

Comment: Yes, there are a index on T_MASTER including all FIELDn fields, but due to how the criteria is written is not used (equal or null).

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or is your `JOIN` criteria effectively you have *N* number of rules and all the rules must match, or the foreign rule must be NULL for any given value of *N*?

Comment: I added some example of rules.

Comment: Each RULE can match any number of rows in MASTER.  So in worst case scenario, that query can return NxM rows (500k x 2k with my figures)

Comment: What use is `master.key = rules.key`?  That is, what role does `key` play?

Comment: KEY is a FOREIGN KEY from a 3rd TABLE with is used to partition the data.  To provide more information, this application is supporting Workspaces (KEY is the workspace ID) where data is loaded for analysis (into MASTER) and the intention of this query is to apply TAGS into MASTER rows based on the rules defined.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One brute force idea is `union all` with all combinations:

```
SELECT master.FIELD_X, rules.FIELD_Y 
FROM T_MASTER master INNER JOIN
     T_RULES rules
     ON master.KEY = rules.KEY AND
        master.FIELD1 = rules.FIELD1 
        master.FIELD2 = rules.FIELD2
WHERE master.KEY = <value>
UNION ALL
SELECT master.FIELD_X, rules.FIELD_Y 
FROM T_MASTER master INNER JOIN
     T_RULES rules
     ON master.KEY = rules.KEY AND
        rules.FIELD1 IS NULL AND
        master.FIELD2 = rules.FIELD2
WHERE master.KEY = <value>
UNION ALL
SELECT master.FIELD_X, rules.FIELD_Y 
FROM T_MASTER master INNER JOIN
     T_RULES rules
     ON master.KEY = rules.KEY AND
        master.FIELD1 = rules.FIELD1 AND
        rules.FIELD2 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT master.FIELD_X, rules.FIELD_Y 
FROM T_MASTER master INNER JOIN
     T_RULES rules
     ON master.KEY = rules.KEY AND
        rules.FIELD1 IS NULL AND
        rules.FIELD2 IS NULL;
```

This is not a really satisfying solution.  However, each subquery should be able to make use of appropriate indexes.  There are 2^n subqueries, where `n` is the number of fields being compared, so this starts to get rather cumbersome starting with 4 or 5 fields.

EDIT:

This is hopeless.  Well, not really.  It is only hopeless because of your data structure.  What you need is a `RulesClauses` table with one row per *exact* match.  Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT m.FIELD_X, r.rule_name
FROM T_MASTER master m CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('FIELD1', Field1),
             ('FIELD2', Field2),
             . . .
             ('FIELDN', FieldN)
     ) v(Field, Val) INNER JOIN

 T_RULES rules r
     ON master.KEY = rules.KEY INNER JOIN
     T_RULESCLAUSES rc
     ON rc.rules_id = r.rules_id AND
        rc.field = v.field AND
        rc.val = v.val
WHERE master.KEY = <value>
GROUP BY m.FIELD_X, r.rule_name, r.clause_count
HAVING COUNT(*) = r.clause_count;
```

Now, the `JOIN` between each clause and each field is an equi-join and can make use of an index on `T_RULESCLAUSES`.

Comment: I though on this, but rules are defined by 9 FIELDS, so the number of subqueries could be high.

Comment: What's 512 subqueries among friends ?  ;)

Comment: Yep! Thinking in a different approach... Iterate through rows in T_RULES with a cursor and produce the SQL query on T_MASTER dynamically based on fields not null.  What do you think?